# How can I put large numbers in a single csv field?

Tags: python

I'm having trouble adding large numbers in to csv file. If I add like an array of numbers to my csv file, this is what I get in my csv file:

```
 A  B  C  D
[1][0][0][4]
[2][2][1][3]
[3][1][6][7]
```

And what I want is this:

```
  A
[1004]
[2213]
[3167]
```

This is the code that I have:

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime
from unittest import skip
end_date = datetime(day=5, month=10, year=2020, hour=23, minute=59)
fastStudent = []
allPassedStudents = []

# Open the csv file with all of the values that need to be proccesed
with open('OOP_eindopdracht\\fed_results\\WFHBOICT.OOP.20.EPIC.EXPORT.FED.20.csv', 'r') as read_obj:
    # reads the whole table with as seperator ";"
    csv_dict_reader = csv.reader(read_obj, delimiter=';',)
    # Skips the headers
    next(csv_dict_reader)
    for row in csv_dict_reader:
       
        #Looks if us11 is empty or not, if its not empty the student has passed
        if row[11]:
            # puts the students(row[0]) in allpassedStudents so it can be saved in a csv file
            allPassedStudents.append(row[0])
            # Converts the date thats in the csv(row[11]) in to datetime so it can be compared to end_date
            passedDate = datetime.strptime(row[11], '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M')
    
        if passedDate:
            # look if passedDate is before the end_date and if so add it to fastStudent so it can be saved in a csv file
            if passedDate < end_date:
                fastStudent.append(row[0])

    with open("OOP_eindopdracht\\Eindopdracht_3\\Processed_csv_file\\Behaalde_studenten.csv", 'a') as f_object: 
        # Pass the CSV  file object to the writer() function
        print(allPassedStudents)
        writer_object = csv.writer(f_object)
        # Result - a writer object
        # Pass the data in the list as an argument into the writerow() function
        for val in allPassedStudents:
            writer_object.writerow(val) 
            # Close the file object

    with open("OOP_eindopdracht\\Eindopdracht_3\\Processed_csv_file\\Snelle_studenten.csv", 'a') as f_object: 
        # Pass the CSV  file object to the writer() function
        writer_object = csv.writer(f_object)
        # Result - a writer object
        # Pass the data in the list as an argument into the writerow() function
        for value in fastStudent:
            writer_object.writerow(value) 
        # Close the file object
```

I made this snippet just so it's easier to read, not for functional purposes.

Comment: `writer_object.writerow(int("".join(val)))` rather than `writer_object.writerow(val)` I think. Same for the following `writer_object.writerow(value)`

Comment: @JonSG I’m getting an error message that sais “iterable expected, not int”

Comment: If that is not working, we will probably need to see some example data from "WFHBOICT.OOP.20.EPIC.EXPORT.FED.20.csv"